# $X_T$ is a random variable if $X$ is measurable and random time $T$ is finite

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

EDIT: My suggested sets don't make sense. LHS has elements of form $(t,\omega)$, RHS has elements of form $(\omega)$. Currently fixing.

Recalling the definitions: (Let $\mathcal B=\mathcal B([0,\infty])$ below)

- $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\times([0,\infty],\mathcal B)\to ([0,\infty],\mathcal B)$ is measurable means $\{(t,\omega):X_t(\omega)\in A\}\in\mathcal F$ for every $A\in\mathcal B$.
- $T:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to ([0,\infty],\mathcal B)$ is a random time means $T\in\mathcal F$.

I note that for $A\in\mathcal B([0,\infty])$, $\{X_T\in A\}=\{(t,\omega):X_t(\omega)\in A\}\cap\{(t,\omega):T(\omega)=t\}$. The first set is a member of $\mathcal F$ since $X$ is measurable. The second set looks almost like what we want. If $T$ only attained countable values (say, $T=t_k$ for some $k$), we could write the set as a union

$$\{(t,\omega):T(\omega)=t\}=\cup_{k=1}^\infty \{\omega:T(\omega)=t_k\}.$$

Not sure how to extend this argument to the set we want in general; maybe this is not the right approach.

Any tips greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135592/martingales-composed-with-stopping-times/2136087#2136087

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks, your answer in that post clears it up perfectly.